# how to restrict the page content becoming large at the time of split the old frame into multiple frames?

Tags: html, firefox, frameset

I have the frameset like this,

index.html

```
<frameset rows="137px,*" border="0" >
<frame src="first.html" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"/>
<frame src="second.html" noresize="noresize" name="show"/>
</frameset>
```

first.html

```
<a href="home.html" target='show'>Home</a>
```

home.html

```
<frameset rows="20%,*" border="0" >
<frame src="third.html" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"/>
<frame src="fouth.html" noresize="noresize" name="newshow"/>
</frameset>
```

when  I  click the **Home** link in first.html. It will be load on the show frame( home.html).

The home.html is having another two frames. it will be split into two frames. When this split happens all page content become large. How to get rid of this problem.

I am working with firefox 3.0.8. In google-chrome,it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: You question is a bit vague, could you maybe reformulate?

Comment: i still don't understand your question.

Comment: Firefox is currently at version 13. Any particular reason why you're working with a version that's now four years old?

Comment: About 3% (which still is way too much) of internet users uses FF 3 or below http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp .. I think anyone who never updated his browser has to deal with the consequences.